# Update wsdl import location when using Java Endpoint API

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a wsdl first project and deployed my web service via Java's Endpoint API. I can navigate to my original wsdl that's published with the web service using a browser. I notice however that the wsdl doesn't update my wsdl/xsd artifacts to be accessible via the web nor does it serve StockQuote.wsdl in a relative path. How can I get my xsd/wsdl dependencies served up as well via the Endpoint API?

WSDL snippet:

```
<!--    ===     Import Interface     ===    -->
<wsdl:import namespace="http://company.com/StockQuote/v1" location="StockQuote.wsdl"/>
```

Here's my service impl:

```
    @WebService(endpointInterface = "com.mycompany.v1.StockQuotePortType",
        wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdl/StockQuoteService.wsdl",
        portName = "StockQuotePortType", 
        serviceName = "StockQuoteService", 
        targetNamespace = "http://company.com/StockQuote/v1")
public class StockQuotePortTypeImpl implements StockQuotePortType
```

Endpoint Creation:

```
    Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(new StockQuotePortTypeImpl());
    String bindingUrl = "http://0.0.0.0:" + port + "/" + serviceName + "/service";
    endpoint.publish(bindingUrl);
```

Comment: Could you further clarify the question?

Comment: As a client, I want to be able to create a client to the StockQuote service by creating a URL to the wsdl on the StockQuote server. This works if I published the endpoint in a J2EE container but not if I use the Enpoint API.